# Any special considerations on learning based on a cyclic timeseries using LSTM?

Tags: lstm, rnn

I have a time-serie over one year. For each 15 minutes in daylight hours, there is a data point. So basically, a sequence for each day. I would like to benefit this information if possible, I mean resemblance in day sequences. Logically, and without a special knowledge, using RNN blindly on the whole year sequence, might or might not learn from days hypes, although, In the best scenario, the network will learn it all.

In other words, How could I tell the LSTM network, for the next 62 data points, *it is a sequence,* that goes relatively up and down in the same way.

- If it changes anything, I'm using Tensorflow and Keras, and still a n00b.

[image]

Comment: I would try using an input sequence length equal to the period of the cyclic event that you observe in your dataset.

Comment: Well, I thought of this, and tried it on train only, the long process my test data will undergo, not exactly like train did, makes me wait for other suggestions, to test and score. But tell me please, @pcko1 what are the motivations behind this idea, because I didn't see better results in general, knowing the best so far, was using batch_size=1 with sequence_length=1 but this takes a hell of time